# Query WMS in OpenLayers3

Tags: wms, openlayers, cql-filter

In previous versions of OpenLayers, we could filter WMS services with CQL. However, I can't filter my WMS services using CQL or other.

How do I do that in OpenLayers 3?

```
 var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8282/geoserver/Isemri/wms',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'Isemri:mahalleler' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        //query: 'OBJECTID_1=262'
        cql_filter: 'OBJECTID_1=237'
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CQL filter is a [vendor parameter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters) provided by GeoServer, therefore you have to include the `cql_filter` in the `params` string object. OpenLayers 3's `ol.source.TileWMS` object only supports options you can see in the corresponding [API page](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.TileWMS.html).

Also, in OpenLayers 2 you had to include `cql_filter` in the `params` object. Because of its limited input options, you didn't have to define the `params` parameter, just enter them between braces after the url parameter. You can read more about this in the OpenLayers 2 OpenLayers.Layer.WMS [API page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html).

Comment: very very thanks bro ,I tried  your suggestion and it worked ;)
` params: { 'LAYERS': 'Isemri:mahalleler', 'cql_filter': "OBJECTID_1=263" },`

Comment: I'm glad that it worked, you're welcome. :)

Comment: guys does this work in OL3? Not in my case