# CQL Filter not working on OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, javascript, wms

I have a WMS layer published to my GeoServer, and I am calling the WMS layer in a web map using the OpenLayers library, and I can visualize it on the map. However, when I try to use CQL_Filter in the OpenLayers, my service disappears, and there is no error. Here is the snippet of my code.

```
  var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Assignment/wms?',
            params : {'LAYERS':'Assignment:India_State_Boundary', 'TILED':true, 'cql_filter': 'Name=Rajasthan'}
        })
    });
```

On searching on this further, I found a similar post, which was solved using CQL_Filter in the params. However, it was for an older version of OpenLayers, and I am currently on version 6. Any insights on this?

Here is the link to the post: [Query WMS in OpenLayers3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115273/query-wms-in-openlayers3)

Comment: The syntax for the name filter needs single quotes around the value, e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-tiled-forked-jsv1vr?file=/main.js

Comment: Thank You @Mike, this worked for me.